# Need help on INNER JOIN two tables

Tags: mysql

I Have 2 tables:

TABLE A: Clientes_consultas;
FIELDS:

```
id_consulta     | int(11)     
meiocomunicacao | int      
caminhoresposta | int
```

…

TABLE B: meioscomunicacao;
FIELDS:

```
id_meiocomunicacao | int(11)
descricao          | varchar(20)
```

In the table Clientes_consultas (meiocomunicacao and caminhoresposta) are numbers that represent the id_meiocomunicacao in meioscomunicacao table.

I have this query:

```
SELECT clientes_consultas.*, meioscomunicacao.descricao
FROM clientes_consultas
INNER JOIN meioscomunicacao ON meioscomunicacao.id_meiocomunicacao=clientes_consultas.caminhoresposta
WHERE id_consulta=14
```

If I change it to (This is what I want):

```
SELECT clientes_consultas.*, meioscomunicacao.descricao
FROM clientes_consultas
INNER JOIN meioscomunicacao ON meioscomunicacao.id_meiocomunicacao=clientes_consultas.caminhoresposta
INNER JOIN meioscomunicacao ON meioscomunicacao.id_meiocomunicacao=clientes_consultas.meiocomunicacao
WHERE id_consulta=14
```

This will give me the error:  `Not unique table/alias: 'meioscomunicacao'`

How can I resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Mário

Answer (score 5):

`Not unique table/alias` error message tells you what to do: create a different alias for each "meioscomunicacao" reference, like this:

```
SELECT clientes_consultas.*, mc1.descricao
FROM clientes_consultas
INNER JOIN meioscomunicacao mc1 ON mc1.id_meiocomunicacao=clientes_consultas.caminhoresposta
INNER JOIN meioscomunicacao mc2 ON mc2.id_meiocomunicacao=clientes_consultas.meiocomunicacao
WHERE id_consulta=14
```

Note that you need to specify if you want mc1.descricao or mc2.descricao in the results (i.e., from which JOIN do you want the "descricao" field).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and effective answer. That is what I was looking for. Thank you once more. Best regards, Mário